# AWS Lambda : Python Globals() get KeyError

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Even though the expression of 'clazz = globals()[table]' is running without any error on production, but it's getting KeyError at my lambda with same code. This error happens in both case of passing table name by Lambda Test Event and by Transformer in EventBridge.

May I ask why KeyError could have happened?

Test Event

```
"{ \"time\": \"2023-03-26T02:05:00Z\" , \"table\": \"T_Test\" }"
```

Lambda code in Python

```
import os
import sys
import json
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print('event: ', event)
    payload = json.loads(event)
    dateFormatter = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
    time = payload['time']
    table = payload['table']
    tables = table.split(',')
    for table in tables: 
        clazz = globals()[table]
```

Error Message

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'T_Test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
    clazz = globals()[table]
```

Comment: I think you got the answer ,right?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these link to more about `globals()`

https://www.javatpoint.com/python-globals-function

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/globals

```
A Symbol table is defined as a data structure which contains all the necessary information about the program. It includes variable names, methods, classes etc.
```

```
The globals() method returns a dictionary with all the global variables and symbols for the current program.
```

Just print the `print(globals())` you would know what are the key present there.

globals() keeps only those information which is global whether it is a variable or method or class.

All the information of lambda_handler which is local to that function, will be in one key:value pair, like 'lambda_handler':<function f1 at 0x102d89ea0>

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print('event: ', event)
    payload = json.loads(event)
    dateFormatter = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
    time = payload['time']
    table = payload['table']  # here the value of table is T_test
    tables = table.split(',') # here tables is ['T_Test']
    for table in tables: 
        clazz = globals()[table] # now you are trying to find globals()['T_test']
    # hence you are getting the key error because there is not any key as T_test in dict
```

Hope you got to know.
:)

Comment: Many thanks again for your kind instructions ! Still I confused why our current script with 'clazz = globals()[table]' is working, your advice helped me understand my error cause aynway. Thanks :)

Comment: there might be some gloabl variable in globals(), which is why you are getting some value.

Comment: Thanks again, we'll confirm it :)